# Split the section in a Layout in Android

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I am working on a Android Project in which I need to design a User Interface like below image-

[image]

I need to show some text on top as `Student App`, then below that there will be different objects of a `Student`. Suppose if I have `10 Students` then there will be `10 rows` for each student. And in each row there will be image on left hand side, then in the middle some text will be there and then on the right hand side there will be another `three text`.

I made some progress and I have below code. But it's not exact the way I am looking for in the image.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:src="@drawable/action_eating"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp" />
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" >
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:text="test"
            android:textColor="#333"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:text="test2"
            android:textColor="#6699CC"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And I need to make that list scrollable.

Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried using tableview

Comment: or may be `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Not yet. Can you guys provide me an example how to do that?

Comment: [RelativeLayout](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-relativelayout-example/) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Table view how you can create column

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <!-- 2 columns -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:text="Column 1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Column 2" />
    </TableRow>

    <!-- edittext span 2 column -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:text="Column 1 &amp; 2" />
    </TableRow>

    <!-- just draw a red line -->
    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <!-- 3 columns -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="Column 1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Column 2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:text="Column 3" />
    </TableRow>

    <!-- display this button in 3rd column via layout_column(zero based) -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:text="Column 3" />
    </TableRow>

    <!-- display this button in 2nd column via layout_column(zero based) -->
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dip" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:text="Column 2" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Will this be expandable? Suppose if I have 15 students, then it will expand 15 rows with scrollable?

Comment: then create in a list view with custom list item

Answer (score 0):

You need a ListView for your students list, and create a custom class that derives from `ArrayAdapter<Student>` and override `getView()`.  The list of student objects gets passed to the adapter and the adapter gets passed to the ListView.  If you're doing this for a class and your intention is to learn, this is great stuff to get familiar with and is very practical for professional Android development.  For extra credit, find a video on YouTube called "World of ListView" from Google I/O 2012 and make your lists faster than the rest of your classmates.

Comment: Can you provide me the example for the UI how to build that list view? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You add your ListView to your activity layout, and you create a second layout that represents each item in the list.  In your adapter's getView method, you'll inflate that item layout and do the work of getting references to the child controls and setting the appropriate data on them from the Student object.  For the specifics, google things like "android listview custom adapter" or various combinations of the things mentioned in my answer.  I can't write the code for you, but there are tons of examples online, in blogs, open source projects, etc.